# Framework not found GTMOAuth2

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I keep getting this error when compiling an Xcode project and cannot for the life of me figure out what the issue is.

```
ld: framework not found GTMOAuth2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am working from an .xcworkspace with a Podfile that has:

```
  use_frameworks!
      pod 'Firebase', '~> 4.0'
      pod 'Firebase/Core'
      pod 'Firebase/Invites'
      pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
      pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
      pod 'TwitterKit'
      pod 'GoogleSignIn'
      pod 'GTMOAuth2'
```

amongst other things.  It finds all of the platforms save GTMOAuth2.  What is strange is that otherwise everything seems in order - I'm opening the correct `xcworkspace` and definitely not an `xcodeproj`

My Pods directory seems in order:

[image: Pods directory]

In my pods I see it as a target:

[image]

This should do it.  Interestingly, when I add it as a Linked Framework and Library, it comes up gray...

[image]

Also, in the build directory, I see both:
`/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/GTMOAuth2/GTMOAuth2.framework`
and
`./Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/GTMOAuth2/GTMOAuth2.framework`

but to no avail, `GTMOAuth2` is not found.  No clue how to proceed - any tips would be really helpful!  I should mention that I'm new to iOS development and that the project is in the context of a React Native App.

Comment: I have the same issue, have you been able to find any fix for this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

-l"GTMOAuth2" Remove this line [image: Remove this line]
then Compile:)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

- Go to Target -> Build Settings
- Inside Framework Search Paths, delete the paths

Comment: I just get the error 'No such module 'React'' after that